# Yii2 как создать объект 1 раз

Tags: php, yii2

Реализую на сайте многоязычность. Языковые версии храню в базе. Создал для этого компонент который достаёт все из базы для того, что бы его можно было дергать откуда угодно, но проблема в том, что если я например дергаю компонент где нибудь в layout, a потом в контроллере, то происходит несколько одинаковых запросов к базе. Как реализовать так, что бы я происходил 1 запрос к базе и при этом не нужно было бы дергать компонент в каждом контроллере

Comment: Почитайте про `static`

Comment: Можно еще кэшировать данные.